# nested routes with multiple pages nuxt3

Tags: nuxtjs3

I wanted to create a new edit page with a nested route. The following structure builds the foundation for my question.

```
/pages
  /backoffice
    /creators
      /[id].vue
      /[id]
        /edit.vue
        /new.vue <-- newly added
```

If I now want to use `[id].vue`  (this is the #show route) for my `edit.vue` component, I need to use NuxtPage Component inside of `[id].vue`. the `/edit.vue` component than uses the layout of `[id].vue` and adds the `edit.vue` component into the "placeholder" of `NuxtPage`, when requesting `backoffice/creators/:id/edit`. So far so good.
If I now want to add a component called `new.vue`, this isn't available under the url of `backoffice/creators/:id/new`.

How can is solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand your issue correctly.

Your pages structure doesn't work correctly for me: the `[id].vue` page prevent any page inside the `[id]` folder to be recognized.

It works correctly by moving the `[id].vue` page inside the `[id]` folder and by renaming it to `index.vue`.

The new pages structure is:

```
/pages
  /backoffice
    /creators
      /[id]
        /index.vue
        /edit.vue
        /new.vue
```

You can find a working project [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-emm7ip)